# Is there an API for navigating the Contents of a Drive shared folder url ?

Tags: google-api, google-drive-api

I have a Google Drive Shared folder URL
I can manually navigate the URL to see/download files.
Is there an API to traverse the contents of this folder ?

The Dropbox API allows you you use the /files/list_files call with a shared_link in the arguments. Then the path is relative to this shared folder.
I would like to do the same with the Google Drive API, or alternate API.

I would prefer NOT to require an authentication token ... since the content is already world readable ... but that is not a hard requirement.

Answer (score 0):

> I have a Google Drive Shared folder URL I can manually navigate the URL to see/download files. Is there an API to traverse the contents of this folder ?

The google drive api has a method called files.list which contains a q parameter which will allow you to search for files only in the sheared folder.

> I would prefer NOT to require an authentication token ... since the content is already world readable ... but that is not a hard requirement.

How exactly do you intend for the API to know who the files are shared with unless you are authenticated?  You cant do a shared with the world or shared public. In order to access data owned by or shared with a user you must be authenticated. The only way for the api to access public data is for you to give the api the file id of the file in question.  There is no way to return all public files on google drive.

Comment: Usually I have a drive user so the Authentication is not a problem. But I have a use case where I do not have a drive user but I do have a shared folder URL that is valid fom that user. (i,e it is WORLD readable). In that case I could use some dummy drive user to access the WORLD readable directory. I will review files.list with a q parameter that specifies a shared folder  ... and post back my results.

Comment: I have not been able to move forward on this ... I can see the sharedWithMe field ... but that is only valid if the file was explicitly shared to me. The user created a SHARED link for a folder ... I have the SHARED link (in particular it contains the Google Drive File ID ... but I can't seem to access it using the files/list or files/get unless I am connected to the account that owns the file.

Comment: OK ... I found out if I share the file "Public on the web - Anyone on the Internet can find and view" than I can use the files/list and files/get on the Google File ID from another account. But I want to do this when I get a URL to share ... So I need to option to provide the URL has a "Validation" that I have access to the file.